# Spring Framework does not call BeanPostProcessor unless a @autowired dependency exists

Tags: java, spring

I am building a TCP Socket Server which uses Spring Framework (3.2.3.RELEASE) to tie things together.

Everything is configured using Java Config with Annotations. In the Java Config I have a `@ComponentScan` annotation to scan for components in my classpath.

When messages are received by the TCP Socket Server, I occasionally want to dispatch some events. For this I use Google Guice EventBus. I don't want the TCP Socket Server to know about the event receivers and vice versa, to keep things loosely coupled.

I have registered a `EventBusRegisterBeanPostProcessor` from the code supplied by Patrick Meade @ http://pmeade.blogspot.no/2013/02/using-guava-eventbus-with-spring-part-2.html

This will scan any bean and register it to the EventBus.

To listen for events (subscribe), I just need to create a POJO which looks like the following:

```
@Component
public class PingMessageReceivedHandler {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PingMessageReceivedHandler.class);

    @Subscribe
    public void handleMessageReceivedEvent(MessageReceivedEvent messageReceivedEvent) {
        logger.info(messageReceivedEvent.getMessage());
        messageReceivedEvent.getChannel().writeAndFlush(new BaseMessage(false, "Pong", null, ""));
    }

}
```

**Now, here is the issue:** Unless I, somewhere in a different service or component or whatever, place a dependency on `PingMessageReceivedHandler` (using for instance `@Autowired`), then the `EventBusRegisterBeanPostProcessor` will not be aware of the `PingMessageReceivedHandler` and as such not dispatch messages to it.

I know that Spring is aware of the existence of the `PingMessageReceivedHandler` as the logs state so:

```
2013-11-04 17:35:05,391  INFO [main] (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:596) - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9695ed7: defining beans [[...],pingMessageReceivedHandler,[...],eventBusRegisterBeanPostProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Any ideas of what is causing this, and even more importantly, how I fix it?

**Edit:**
Context configuration:

```
@ComponentScan(value = "com.company.product")
@Configuration
public class DeviceManagerServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public static EventBusRegisterBeanPostProcessor eventBusRegisterBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new EventBusRegisterBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public EventBus eventBus() {
        return new EventBus("standard");
    }
}
```

It is initialized using:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.register(DeviceManagerServerConfig.class);
context.refresh();
```

Comment: Add a default constructor to the handler and place a breakpoint in it. See if that gets hit when you start up your application.

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't get hit unless I depend on the class (@Autowired somewhere)

Comment: Please post your context configuration.

Comment: Added context configuration.

Comment: Can you please add the implementation of your EventBusRegisterBeanPostProcessor or does it exactly match that in the blog post?

Comment: Its exactly the same as the blog post, just with another name. I'll rename the post to have the same name everywhere, so that there is no confusion.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem. Note that you don't need `static` for your `EventBusRegisterBeanPostProcessor` bean method. `static` is only needed for `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` beans.

Comment: Could Maven affect it? Or AspectJ? I use some AspectJ stuff for databases (Spring Roo). A temporary hack that worked for me for this issue is to just use `@Autowired private Collection<Object> everything`. But I consider that one a hack, as I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: @aldrian Maven, no. AspectJ yes. Please post a reproducible example. As it stands, the `BeanPostProcessor` will process your `PingMessageReceivedHandler` component. Respond to me (or others) with `@Sotirios` so I can get a notification.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis found the issue, I was initializing a bean with a blocking operation which caused the issues. When I moved the blocking operation after `context.refresh()` it solved everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I attempted to initialize a bean which has a blocking operation (the TCP Socket Server).

This stopped Spring from further bean initialization, and caused the issue in the Original post.

I.e:

```
@Component
@Profile("default")
public class SocketServerImpl implements SocketServer {
    /**
    * Instantiates a new socket server.
    */
    public SocketServerImpl() {
        /* Standard stuff */
    }


    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    public void start() {
        /* This would block any further progressing */
    }
}
```

My fix was pretty simple, I removed `@PostConstruct` from the code above, and in my `public static void main`, after I called `context.refresh()`, I called `context.getBean(SocketServer.class).start()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
@Lazy(false)
```

to your handler bean.

I think it is declared lazy by default somehow and is therefore not loaded on startup without a dependency.